# The stored procedure 'EDA_TRUSTEES_GETTRUSTEETOKEN_X' doesn't exist

Tags: web8.5

After restoring the Content Manager database of our SDL Web 8.5 CME I get the following error:

> The stored procedure 'EDA_TRUSTEES_GETTRUSTEETOKEN_82' doesn't exist.

[image]
 I added the user to the TRUSTEE table but I am still getting this error.

Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

I installed: Hofix CM_8.5.0.10663, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Peter - sounds like you’re missing a hitfix perhaps.? Have you checked?

Comment: Hi @Dylan..MarkSaunders, I will check. Do you have any advice to which HotFix this might be related?

Comment: I installed hotfix: CM_8.5.0.10663. But still no effect.

Comment: _82 - seems it's introduced in version 8.2, How come this missed for you in your 8.5 DB, either your upgrade script something went wrong during your upgrade, I would recommend raising this to SDL support?

Comment: @Velmurugan, we upgraded from SDL 2013 SP1 to SDL Web 8.5. I also raised a ticket at SDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We requested a copy of the Content Management DB, but our hosting supplier delivered a copy of the old 2013 SP1 installation.

[image]

So this error happens when you restore a 2013 SP1 database in your SDL Web 8.5 CME...

Comment: We got the same error after running the upgrade script (also from 2013 SP1 to 8.5) with integrated security. As a result, schema of the created stored procedures wasn't 'dbo' but user which ran the scripts and that's why stored procedures were reported to be missing. I'm still not sure whether this was caused by a bug in the script of insufficient db permissions.