# Tridion is throwing database error while loading

Tags: sites-9

[image]could someone please help why tridion sites is throwing database error

```
error: A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_TRUSTEES_GETTRUSTEETOKEN_82"
Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The wait operation timed out
  Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 831 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
```

Comment: Please include additional information like, is it a fresh installation or an upgraded instance, did it work at any point, etc.

Comment: @Atila, it is a fresh installation, it works sometime, but sometime it throws db errors

Comment: Just to confirm - you've started with a clean database and not a restored (from a previous...) version? If you restored then see https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19919/the-stored-procedure-eda-trustees-gettrusteetoken-x-doesnt-exist

Comment: It is pretty common to see the above error in a restored database as @Dylan already pointed out. If it happens sporadically, it could be an issue with your database. Are you having any maintenance scripts to analyse your database stats? Can you check if all of your stored procedures are successfully compiled?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a typical Timeout error on a database pointing to lacking database maintenance or database upgraded or restored, It's expected to run the stats update.

The first thing to check is whether you have regular database maintenance performed? If not, do one (and start doing it on a **regular basis**, if possible daily) and try again. Database maintenance (Tridion specific) described [here](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/maintaining-sdl-tridion-databases).

You could increase the timeouts as described [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-43FE936B-56BF-468F-AA2C-340514B7776E) might help to resolve your issue.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting your CM database server and/or looking at the maximum database memory settings, like [this](http://www.stugr.com/2013/01/24/wsus-limit-sql-windows-internal-database-memory/)? I had a similar issue and I noticed the CM database server was out of memory, so I restarted it to resolve the issue. Then I noticed the database memory settings were set to the default maximum...